# Overriding buttons for change form in admin does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to override the `change_form.html` for a specific app/model, but it is not working at all.

This is the file structure i have:

```
webapp
-- \admin
-- -- \templates
-- -- -- \admin
-- -- -- -- \backend
-- -- -- -- -- \someentity
-- -- -- -- -- -- \change_form.html
-- \backend
-- \webapp
```

As you can see i have an app called `backend` with a model called `someentity`, which i want to override in the admin on the `change_form.html`.

I am using following template loaders:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Comment: Your it should be in `templates/admin/backend/someentity/change_form.html` not `admin/template/admin/backend/someentity/change_form.html`

Comment: I've added it as an answer so that you can accept it and close the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template should be in `templates/admin/backend/someentity/change_form.html` not `admin/template/admin/backend/someentity/change_form.html`